# CSS selector for optional children/descendants

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector for optional children/descendants, so that instead of writing

```
a:link,
a:link * {
  color: red;
}
```

I can write something like this:

```
a:link ?* {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: what's the scenario you are trying to solve?

Comment: You will probably be better off just trusting inheritance rather than trying to get any cleverer with your selectors. Just select the stuff you want to target.

Comment: In just CSS, no.

Comment: OK, so there is no such an option, thanks.

Comment: No such operator in CSS. Sometimes you just have to write multiple rules. (Note that the `color` property is inherited.)

Comment: If you give us a scenario(s), we can understand the issue better and most likely have a better solution for what you have now